# How can one search for some text in one's deleted chat messages?

Tags: support, chat, search

I've had a few chat messages deleted by a mod and feeds in some chat room. I am looking for a few sentences I wrote in these chat messages. How can one search for some text in one's deleted chat messages? Otherwise, how can one search for some text in one's chat messages including deleted chat messages? Assume that the chat message's history has not been purged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there's no stock way to do this, it is possible to write code that downloads all the messages in a room, then goes through the ones which were authored by you and deleted. For those, you could then obtain the message text from each message history page. At that point, you'd have all the text for the messages in that room which were by you, including deleted, but excluding any where the content was overwritten and history was purged. You could do that for every room on the chat server, including deleted rooms, which would give you all the messages by you, except those in private rooms to which you no longer have access (and excluding those messages where the content had been overwritten and history purged). You could then search through the text of the messages.

Answer (score 10):

You can't.

There is no way to search deleted chat messages, especially if the history has been purged (since even employees with database access won't have access to it if it's been purged). Your only option is to manually look back through each deleted message that appears in the transcript to see if you can find it.

I would question *why* you'd want to find this, though. If it's been flag-deleted or mod-deleted, that's a pretty strong signal that it's not considered acceptable content. Think carefully about whether it's really worth re-posting content that's already been deemed unacceptable for the platform.

Comment: Thanks. No intent to repost.

Comment: Why does it matter why he needs it? It was his content may be he needs to review it for whatever reason and is trying to see if there is way to find it again or not. I don't see any intent to repost in the OP

Comment: It's quite the same like comments. You can't search for your deleted comments, and usually no point doing it anyway.